# .Net Core How to control authorization policy on a Dynamic Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization, asp.net-core-mvc

.Net Core 2 allows you to create dynamic controllers as seen in their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts)

```
public class GenericControllerFeatureProvider : IApplicationFeatureProvider<ControllerFeature>
{
    public void PopulateFeature(IEnumerable<ApplicationPart> parts, ControllerFeature feature)
    {
        foreach (var entityType in EntityTypes.Types)
        {
            var typeName = entityType.Name + "Controller";
            if (!feature.Controllers.Any(t => t.Name == typeName))
            {                
                var controllerType = typeof(GenericController<>)
                    .MakeGenericType(entityType.AsType())
                    .GetTypeInfo();
                feature.Controllers.Add(controllerType);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On some Controller you might specify an authorization role like so:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public controller HomeController : Controller
{
}
```

With Generic Controllers you may want to specify different roles and policies per implementation.

How can you specify different roles and policies for authorization on dynamic controllers?

Comment: Have you tried putting `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` on the `GenericController<T>` class? And did you mean "role" instead of "policy" in your question?

Comment: @NightOwl888 That would work if all of the controller had the same roles, but I'm providing a rest framework for an enduser, and they need to be able to control the roles on each controller,  So one might be for Administrators, while the other is allow anonymous

Comment: @NightOwl888 yes sorry I was using the wrong terminology, I've edited to clarify

Comment: Maybe not. This feels like something that you could work around by using a [custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies) something like `[Authorize(Policy = "MyPolicy")]` and then make the policy apply the roles based on the controller that is being accessed. For example, inject a service into the policy that the user could manipulate at runtime to change the roles.

Comment: @NightOwl888 That's genius,  That should work perfect.  I understand the concept fine, but I always like to pay it forward, so if you post a small answer or proof of concept on this I'll accept and upvote